# how to make a mouseleave on CSS?

Tags: javascript, css

I created a UL and it's li as a searchbox, and I want this list to disappear when the mouse is out of the div that wraps the searchbox. I managed this using plain JS doing this:

```
document.querySelector('.wrapperElasticLi').addEventListener('mouseleave', function(event) { event.target.style.display = 'none' })
```

But it was rejected as they told me they don't want this using javascript and told me to do it via CSS.

What would be the CSS way?

Thanks

Comment: `:hover { display: block }`

Answer (score 2):

This could work:

```
ul {display:none;}
.container:hover ~ ul { display: block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code example. Hide the search box by default, and then trigger the searchbox to show when you hover on the `.container`. You can hover parents to trigger css events for children or an adjacent sibling, but you can't trigger grandparents. Take a look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp) for more info, and another working example.

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background: #efefef;
  padding: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}
ul.searchbox {
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
}
ul.searchbox li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.container:hover .searchbox {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  This is a container.
  <ul class="searchbox">
   <li>
      Search:<br>
     <input type="text">
   </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```